# summaryType ExtJS - Summary Type of a filtered column

Tags: extjs

I am trying to get total of a column in ExtJS Summary grid (ExtJS4.2). I used the following code:

```
      summaryType: 'sum',            
      summaryType: function(records){               
            var helpDuration=0;
        Ext.Array.forEach(records, function (record){
            helpDuration += record.data.actualduration;
        });
            return helpDuration;
        }
```

But when I filter the grid based on another column, it shows the filtered rows but the summary remains the same, it does not get auto-recalculated. Am I missing anything here?

Appreciate the help.

Comment: i mean, in both the cases, it did not auto-calculate the filtered records' duration field.

Answer (score 0):

At first look, I'ld say that having the same configuration property declared twice (SummaryType) might be your problem, your custom sum function probably never get called because the line above specify to use the built in function.

Try remove

```
summaryType: 'sum'
```

Then place a `debugger;` in your function to see what's happening.

Comment: thanks for your response, basically it's not calling that JS part when I filtered it. So on filtering, I should refresh so that that piece of code gets re-triggered?